# OleDbCommand with 'where in' and dbParameter

Tags: c#, sql, ms-access, oledbcommand

I try to delete some rows from a table in an access database file via C#.
This attempt fails with no error which leads me to the conclusion that I have a valid query with incorrect data.

I tried to see if I can query the data with a select statement from my code and I can narrow the problem down to the parameters.

The statement should look as follows

```
SELECT * FROM tbIndex where pguid in ('4a651816-e15b-4c6a-85c4-74033ca6c423', '0add7bff-a22f-4238-9c7f-e1ff4ed3c7e2', '742fae8b-2692-4a6f-802c-848fad570696', '5e6b65de-2403-4800-a47d-e57c7bd8e0a6')
```

I tried two different ways*(dbCmd2 and dbCmd3)* from which the first*(dbCmd2)* works but is, due to injection problems, not my prefered solution.

```
using (OleDbCommand dbCmd2 = new OleDbCommand { Connection = m_Connection })
{
    dbCmd2.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbIndex where pguid in ("+pguid+")";
    using (DbDataReader reader = dbCmd2.ExecuteReader())
    {
        List<object[]> readValuesFromIndex = new List<object[]>();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            //Point reached
            object[] arr = new object[reader.VisibleFieldCount];
            reader.GetValues(arr);
            //...
        }
        reader.Close();
    }

    using (OleDbCommand dbCmd3 = new OleDbCommand { Connection = m_Connection })
    {
        dbCmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbIndex where pguid in (@pguid)";
        dbCmd3.Parameters.Add("@pguid", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = pguid;
        using (DbDataReader reader = dbCmd3.ExecuteReader())
        {
            List<object[]> readValuesFromIndex = new List<object[]>();
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                //Point not reached
                object[] arr = new object[reader.VisibleFieldCount];
                reader.GetValues(arr);
                //...
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
    }
```

*Note that `pguid` is set to `"'4a651816-e15b-4c6a-85c4-74033ca6c423', '0add7bff-a22f-4238-9c7f-e1ff4ed3c7e2', '742fae8b-2692-4a6f-802c-848fad570696', '5e6b65de-2403-4800-a47d-e57c7bd8e0a6'"`.*

I always thought that the second option would simply replace the parameter in a safe manner but this is obviously not the case.

My question is:
**Why doesn't the second option return any values?**

Comment: The first query is open to SQL Injection, and thus **must not** be used. The second will, almost certainly, not work.

Comment: PetaPoco, and other ORMs, have support for IN clauses built in (https://redeyedmonster.co.uk/petapoco-documentation/ - `When using a WHERE IN clause`). Have you considered that as an option here?

Comment: What you **think** you are asking is for the server to match on any of the entries in `'4a651816-e15b-4c6a-85c4-74033ca6c423', '0add7bff-a22f-4238-9c7f-e1ff4ed3c7e2', '742fae8b-2692-4a6f-802c-848fad570696', '5e6b65de-2403-4800-a47d-e57c7bd8e0a6'` But what you are **actually** asking it is to match any of a set of entries. **Alas the one (and only) entry in that set** is `'4a651816-e15b-4c6a-85c4-74033ca6c423', '0add7bff-a22f-4238-9c7f-e1ff4ed3c7e2', '742fae8b-2692-4a6f-802c-848fad570696', '5e6b65de-2403-4800-a47d-e57c7bd8e0a6'` (note that is a **single** string, not four strings).

Comment: So, you need to pass not a single parameter, like you are doing. You need to pass **four** parameters (one for each of the strings). PetaPoco and other ORMs will do this for you automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A parameter always is a *single* value.

An in clause requires multiple values, separated by comma's.

You can do something like the following to pass them like separate parameters:

```
string[] guids = pguid.Split(',');
string sqlin = "";
int paramno = -1;
foreach (var guid in guids)
{
   parametercount ++;
   sqlin = sqlin + "@Param" + (string)parametercount; + ","
}
dbCmd3.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM tbIndex where pguid in (" + sqlin.Substring(0, sqlin.Length-1) + ")";
for(int i = 0; i <= parametercount; i++){
    dbCmd3.Parameters.Add("@Param" + (string)i, OleDbType.VarChar).Value = guids[i].Replace("'", "");
}
```

Comment: Also consider using `Enumerable.Range` and `string.Join` to avoid the need to iterate over `guids` to generate the `params`.

Comment: Thanks you. Your answer is right so +1. Since @mjwills wrote the answer first in the comments I would mark his answer as the accepted one, if mjwills doesn't write an answer I will make this the accepted answer.